# circles not displaying on svg as per dataset

Tags: svg, display

I am very new to D3, I am just trying to create circles according a very small 2 dimension, 4 element array, initialized in code , below, but only one circle is displayed. not sure why? if anyone can help to point out what is the problem?

one note: array elements d.x and d.y are carrying data elements. I have verified in console.log(d.x) and console.log(d.y):

```
 //   below is index.js file

         //this is array
           const myArr = [{x: 100 , y: 100},
                            {x: 130 , y: 150},
                            {x: 77 , y: 120},
                            {x: 90 , y: 49}];
            const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("height" , 200)
                .attr("width" , 350);


     below is the code to handle svg selection , enter , update

             const circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(myArr);

             //enter
            circles.enter().append("circle")
                 .attr("r" , 8);
                   //.attr("fill", "#00aa88");
            //update
                circles.attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                    .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y;  });

                svg.selectAll("text")
                    .data(myArr)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.x + "," + d.y;
                    })
                    .attr("x", function (d) {
                        return d.x;
                    })
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return d.y;
                    })
                    .attr("font-size", "15px")
                    .attr("fill", "white");
            //exit
                circles.exit().remove();

       this code displays on one circle. i have not added any axes yet.

    index.html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <title>Practise</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>PRACTICE</h2>
    <circle></circle>

    </body>
    </html>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

one more quesiton, if i call this index.js in head code does not work , it only works if i call this script file at very bottom of index.html. if anyone can help why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: Your circles have a radius but not a `cx` and/or `cy`, as a consequence all your circles are drawn with the center in the origin of the SVG canvas (left upper corner). Besides in tour HTML you have a `<circle>` element.  A `<circle>` element should be always drawn in a `<svg>` element